# When to expect declined flags and how do I react to that?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, serial-voting

I've been flagging a lot of posts recently with more complicated reasoning than the standard flags allow. On response to that I've gotten several declined flags and it got me thinking, when can I expect to have declined flags and what can I do about it?

In this particular topic I'm flagging stuff in (serial voting), I can't tell the exact circumstances of an incident any more accurately than I already do - any form of direct voting information is privileged to moderators and CMs only. All I can do (and have done so far) is flag on suspicion.

For two recent flags in particular, I actually know that I couldn't have known no action was necessary on the moderator side - that is privileged information only moderators are allowed to access. Yet, my flags on these posts were declined.

So given that, do I just have to live with the fact that I'll eat a couple declined flags now and then (and maybe a flag ban if I get unlucky enough)?

Is this a sign that my methods for determining flags aren't accurate enough and I should stop with the current strategy? In all my other flagging endeavours declined flags have always meant a firm "You shouldn't have flagged that and if you keep doing that we'll apply a penalty to your account."

Edit: I have elected to discontinue the activity mentioned above. Sorry for wasting everyone's time with this.

Comment: No one can predict the future, except maybe weather forecasters and they screw up big times now and then .....

Comment: Also: if you've raise 5 flags in total and 4 got declined I would be worried. If you've raised 3117 helpful flags with a low fail rate I wouldn't be bothered by some declines.

Comment: Mods have been reviewing your flags and it takes time and indeed many (the majority) of these flags are helpful. The essence of the issue here, is coming to terms with a declined flag. I have over 100 declined flags, but that's because I also took some risks in my flagging - like you are - asking for a bounty to be removed on an offtopic question so it could be closed. Suspected serial voting. The less standard the flag the higher the risk. You know mods are limited. The cm are time limited. It's not that people don't care about voting fraud, it just takes time to investigate it..

Comment: .. the community cannot tell you whether you should continue, only you can decide that. If you cannot cope with declined flags, the only foolproof way to avoid that is to not flag at all.

Answer (score 40):

First off, I don't think you need to worry about a flag ban. You have over 1800 helpful post flags and only 14 declined. Of those, only 4 declined flags came within calendar 2018 among hundreds of helpful flags in that period. If you keep flagging in the way you are, you'll do just fine.

When you started flagging serial voting, you had wanted us to provide feedback on your flags to refine your search techniques. Of the five declined flags you've received on your serial voting ones, four of them were for cases where even the public reputation history of the user didn't show what you had indicated. These looked like misfires on the wrong user, and we wanted to let you know about these. They were things like telling us that a user had 8 posts upvoted, but the user only had two posts total, so that wasn't even possible.

The last declined flag was on something that was moderator-only. In general, my policy for flags on potential voting fraud is to default to marking them as helpful unless the flagger is wildly off-base in a way they should have been able to see. If there was no indication of fraud on our end, I'll often mark the flag as helpful and leave a custom response that states why this wasn't the case (without exposing any private information). If there was no way for someone to know they were wrong, and all public signs point to something fishy, I know you meant well with your flag.

That's what I've been doing with your serial voting flags, trying to provide feedback on the ones that were not an issue on our end so that you can refine your search. I've reserved declining these for clear and publicly visible errors, to highlight those.

Overall, these flags have been very helpful, and if you keep up like you have you don't have anything to worry about. You might hit an occasional decline due to differences in how people process these, but so have all of us.

Comment: "I'll often mark the flag as helpful and leave a custom response" It's worth noting that until a little while ago (maybe a year or so) this wasn't possible, so the only way for mods to give such feedback was to decline, but now this feature exists.  (I mention this because users may see outdated advice elsewhere with mods saying that they'll decline such posts in order to give a reason.)

Answer (score 12):

I really wouldn't sweat it.

Sure, you can feel good having a helpful flag count of in the tens of thousands, but if all those flags did was get rid of benign comments, are you *really* being that helpful?

I'd rather see people flag all genuinely suspicious behavior they see and get a flag or two declined now and then than not flagging such things at all in fear of getting flag banned.

In comparison, 75% of my flags are on posts, I have a decline percentage of around 5% (47/1025) (most of which were declined NAA/VLQ flags) and I still get 100 flags a day to use.

That being said, I don't think flags should be declined if you're reporting suspicious activity to the best of your ability and it turns out to be a false positive, would it really hurt for the moderator to click the canned response that goes something like *"helpful - thanks, we'll look into it"*?

Comment: Flag ban doesn't happen over a few declined flags, right?

Comment: I don't think so, rene.

Comment: @rene I know of one user that got flag banned over 3 declined spam flags. It was only for a week (until the rolling ban moved on), but they still got banned.

Comment: It's based on the proportion of recent flags that were declined. So if you have 1000 helpful flags but **your last 10** flag were declined you are in danger of being banned.

Comment: Flag bans occur if in the past week you've cast ≥10 flags and ≥3 of them were declined. They wear off within a week.

Comment: the condescending "make sure you're _really_ sure" warning happens if 1 in the 10 last flags of you that got handled was declined, iirc.

Comment: I tend to agree with you on the marking it helpful - with good faith flags.

Answer (score 8):

> So given that, do I just have to live with the fact that I'll eat a couple declined flags now and then (and maybe a flag ban if I get unlucky enough)?

Short answer:

Yes.

Longer answer:

Perhaps you need to slow down with your flags and/or raise other flags unrelated to serial voting at the same time so that when you do get a flag declined - as will inevitably happen - it will cause less of an impact.

> any form of direct voting information is privileged to moderators and CMs only

Moderators don't have that much more information about direct voting. All we see is aggregate data which only gives us patterns, not specific information. You're working at the limits of what the moderators can see. You might be better off contacting the CMs directly with this information. If it's useful they can either act on the data you send them as you send it or build your algorithm into the tools for moderators.

Comment: I've always thought if I did things right I should have 0 declined flags. Obviously that's a pipe dream, but what do I do when I get a declined flag on something I flagged in good faith and with my best judgement using all the information available to me? Does that just mean I'll have to eat those anyways?

Comment: To me, a declined flag means "You need to adjust your behavior and if you don't, we'll ban you for wasting our time"

Comment: @Magisch You are raising flags about things that we don't have that much more information about so some flags will get declined as we won't necessarily see what you see. Why don't you send the information direct to the CMs?

Comment: @Magisch you need to adjust your behaviour and change your interpretation of declined flags.

Comment: @ChrisF By shog's own admission they already have better tools then I do on the CM side. That means sifting through all of that cruft is not a priority on the CM side - from what I know not all of the cases I flag get escalated. So in essence that just means I stop flagging, I mean, fair enough.

Comment: @Magisch that's not what ChrisF seems to be saying. I don't think anybody wants you to stop flagging voting rings, I take it you're good at it. Just expect a few declines every now and then, or diversify your flag portfolio if you want an even smaller declined ratio. (This is not to say that I agree with the declines, just interpreting the response.)

Comment: @AndrasDeak indeed. With the tools we moderators have available we can't see much more than Magisch so there will be some interpretation going on - hence the occasional decline.

Comment: Could you suggest the preferred method to contact CMs in bulk, in a way which wastes as little amount of people's time as necessary?

Comment: @angussidney I'm not sure there is a preferred way. I've always addressed one issue per contact.

Comment: _You might be better off contacting the CMs directly with this information_: How? We don't have an _Ask a mod_ chat like Super User does. As I understood, mod flags are the preferred way to contact mods about specific posts.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth there's a contact form linked at the bottom of every page. That goes to the CMs. Flagging *is* the preferred way, but we're talking about cases where mods can't do much more than pass the flag straight onto the CMs anyway.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth anyway - "ask a mod" is not "ask a CM"

Comment: Ah, got my terminology confused. Sorry.